# What is the name of this construction?

Tags: grammar, construction

I've got an excerpt from a book here and I want to know what kind of grammatical construction this is:

> He set off for the stairs with the others **trailing after him**.

I want to research it, but I don't know what it's called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what is known as a participial phrase, which consists of a participle (a verb functioning as an adjective ["trailing" in this case, modifying "others"]) and its modifiers (the prepositional phrase "after him").